# Unable to install Springseed 2 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, 15.04, libgcrypt

I've downloaded Springseed 2 `deb` file and when I open it by Ubuntu Software Center, it shows this error:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libgcrypt11

I've looked for this package in my Synaptic Package Manager, there is a `libgcrypt20` but nothing for `libgcrypt11`.

How should resolve this problem?

Comment: Where did you download the file from?

Comment: @Wilf From [Springseed homepage](http://getspringseed.com/)

Comment: @abforce: see the answer below

Comment: Aside: Your old notes from, say, Springseed 1.1 apparently don't carry over if you upgrade to 2.0. I had to go back to 1.1 and manually export them, and then put them back into the newer version.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You have two options

- Change the dependencies and use the latest `libgcrypt`

  There are multiple reasons we're up to `libgcrypt20`
- Install `libgcrypt11` and use an *old* version of `libgcrypt`

---

**Change the dependencies:**

First, remove the previous installation of SpringSeed:

```
sudo apt-get remove springseed
```

Download the latest SpringsSeed version [here](http://getspringseed.com/):

E.G.:

```
cd
wget http://cdn.michealharker.com/dl/springseed_2.0_amd64.deb
```

Follow these commands

```
mkdir temp.$$
cp springseed_2.0_amd64.deb temp.$$
cd temp.$$
dpkg-deb -x springseed_2.0_amd64.deb springseed-repackaged
cd springseed-repackaged
dpkg-deb -e ../springseed_2.0_amd64.deb
```

Open the `control` file:

```
nano DEBIAN/control
```

replace the line:

```
Depends: gconf2, gconf-service, libgtk2.0-0, libudev0 | libudev1, libgcrypt11, libgnome-keyring0, gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0, libnotify4, libxtst6, libnss3, python
```

with:

```
Depends: gconf2, gconf-service, libgtk2.0-0, libudev0 | libudev1, libgcrypt20, libgnome-keyring0, gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0, libnotify4, libxtst6, libnss3, python
```

Save and exit and follow these commands:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg-deb -b springseed-repackaged
sudo dpkg -i springseed-repackaged.deb
```

---

**Install `libgcrypt11`**

Open a terminal and download the latest Utopic version for `libgcrypt11`:

```
cd
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Download the latest Springseed version [here](http://getspringseed.com/), eg:

```
wget http://cdn.michealharker.com/dl/springseed_2.0_amd64.deb
```

Install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i springseed_2.0_amd64.deb
```

And it works in Ubuntu 15.04 as well!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, surely your answer does work but I can't mark both answers as accepted.

Comment: maybe, but there is another option. Read.

Comment: Your first option seems more tempting than the second one! `:)`

Comment: Yes, I think, my answer is better.

Comment: I have changed the commands. To many copy and paste from my shell history file. Sorry.

Comment: @A.B.>> yes, I agree, your answer should be followed along

Comment: First remove the previous installation of Snapseed. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The final release of Ubuntu 15.04 no longer keeps the package `libgcrypt11`, rather `libgcrypt20` as you have come across by the Synaptic Package Manager.

All you have to do is to download the package from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb) and then install it prior to `Springseed`. You may earn additional knowledge from [this source](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/04/fix-missing-libgcrypt11-causing-spotify.html) pointing out similar problems with other apps besides `Springseed`.

Please read the content from the second link carefully again if you face any problems.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your answer, but A.B.'s one seems more comprehensive.

Comment: @abforce: His answer is more advanced than is comprehensive. I myself would pick that answer as the best one if I just could :).

Comment: Your answer is good, so I gave you an upvote yesterday evening. :)