# Unable to install latest brackets on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, 15.04

I have latest deb package of [brackets](http://brackets.io/) 64bit. I am on Ubuntu 15.04. I am getting the following error:

```
dependency is not satisfiable: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5)
```

I tried to install `libgcrypt11` then I got this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11
Package libgcrypt11 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgcrypt11' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update**, the version below is not longer available. Now you have to install the Trusty version:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7110687/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

---

The package `libgcrypt11` isn't longer an installable package in Ubuntu 15.04. You need now the library `libgcrypt20`.

Therefore install the latest Utopic package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic-updates/libgcrypt11) with:

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Or follow the steps from my **[previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/627420/367165)** to change the dependencies for the brackets package and use `libgcrypt20`.

Comment: ubuntu 15.04 is newer than utopic right? then why such problem?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I have updated my answer

Comment: Using `libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb` also worked well for getting Spotify to work again in Ubuntu 15.04, thanks!

Comment: mirrors.kernel.org... will throw a 404 use this instead https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7110687/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

Comment: Not on my system.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is install libgcrypt11 from an older Ubuntu version, such as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_i386.deb

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After following the steps from A.B.'s answer, the error didn't go away. I installed Brackets from Ubuntu-After-install.

https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-after-install

1. follow these steps:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-after-install
> ```

2. open ubuntu-after-install from your apps.
3. type-in your password.
4. Select Brackets from the list. It will probably be the last entry in the list and click install. You are ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Brackets via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

You could download the test version package [this page](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/tag/linux-cef-2171) based on [this issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10255)

I'm new to Brackets. The install showed no issues. Only a pop-up came up with the notification that a newer version is available. This is the 1.4 version which doesn't work with libgcrypt20.

**Extra**

I tried following the instructions from [sarathms](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10255#issuecomment-73007571), but version 1.4 won't start this way. From the command line `brackets`

```
/usr/bin/brackets: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Apparently somewhere inside the compiled code, there's a dependency.