# JRE Unmet dependencies, already have oracle JDK

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, jdk

I've installed a .deb package (which requires jre and I already have Oracle JDK) using the command

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

The app runs successfully, but there is an error message in the Ubuntu top panel that says `BrokenCount>0` which means installed packages have unmet dependencies. Until today I've been using the zipped version of that package and it was working fine. But I wanted to give the `.deb` version a try and now I'm in trouble! The package is specifically looking for JRE, which I already have in JDK.

Output of `sudo apt-get check`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xdman : Depends: default-jre but it is not installed or
                  sun-java6-jre but it is not installable or
                  sun-java7-jre but it is not installable or
                  openjdk-6-jre but it is not installed or
                  openjdk-7-jre but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have not run `apt-get -f install` because I am unsure of its result. Is it going to install another JRE? Can I fix this broken dependency issue without installing anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the command `apt-get -f install` installs a new JRE, but that's not a problem, you can correct, *if necessary*, the default JRE with the command below

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And yes, you could change the dependencies of the package. But that's not really necessary. Read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/627459/367165), for a solution.

Comment: For Java, using `update-java-alternatives` is recommended, as there are many programs that make up Java.

Comment: @Eisenheim No upvote for me? ;)

Comment: @A.B. Done. I thought it will require me more Reputations like stackoverflow.